# ESP8266 attachinterrupt + millis ignoring conditional

Tags: c++, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am writing a driver for an anemometer, which is based on the Hall effect and I am trying to use hardware interrupts to monitor every rotation of the sensor.

By doing so I found an issue that I am not able to solve and is expressed by the following code:

```
#if ARDUINO >= 100
 #include "Arduino.h"
#else
 #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

const int interruptPin = D5;
volatile uint16_t lastDebounceTime = 0;
volatile int numberOfInterrupts = 0;
uint16_t previousUpdate = 0;
const uint16_t updateInterval = 5000;
void handleInterrupt();
void countInterrupts();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), handleInterrupt, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  if ((millis() - previousUpdate) > updateInterval) {
    Serial.println(".................");
    uint16_t currentMillis = millis();
    Serial.println(currentMillis);
    Serial.println(previousUpdate);
    Serial.println(currentMillis - previousUpdate);
    if (currentMillis - previousUpdate < updateInterval) Serial.println("This line shoudn't be executed, but it actually is!!");
    Serial.println(".................");
    previousUpdate = millis();
  }
}

void handleInterrupt() {
  numberOfInterrupts++;
}
```

At first the code run as it was supposed to, but after a while it simply stop checking the conditionals `if ((millis() - previousUpdate) > updateInterval)` and `if (currentMillis - previousUpdate < updateInterval) Serial.println("This line shoudn't be executed, but it actually is!!");` and then the at each iteration the ESP8266 sends data to the serial interface. `millis()` is working the interrupt function is working as well.

I'm really trying to understand and solve this problem, it would be awesome if somebody could help me with it!

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with "after a while"? Could it be after about 65 seconds, or 65536 milliseconds? If millis() returns a 32 bit number (does it on your particular platform?) and you truncate previousUpdate to 16 bits, then the first condition will always be true at some point. I'm not sure about the second condition. Does "This line shouldn't be executed" appear at each iteration or just once every 65 seconds?

Comment: Sir you are absolutely right! The size of previousUpdate was the source of all my problems.... Now I am feeling bad for my silly mistake! Thank you mr. mars

Comment: You're welcome, and please don't feel bad about it. We all make mistakes and need to test if things really work as they should. And we all know how valuable a second pair of eyes are when you've been working on a problem for too long.